# jQuery / Javascript - convert datetime to user's timezone datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone, data-conversion

I updated this question

I would like to transform a datetime to the equivalent datetime in the country(timezone) user is located to.

I have datetime in this format which is UTC/GMT:

```
Oct 31, 2012 08:10:02
```

now, according with the user's client timezone i would like to convert that datetime using the current browser/client user's timezone

how can i do that?

Comment: The date time in javascript is `GMT`. And `GMT == UTC`.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean ... do you mean you want to use UTC as input instead of using date string?

Comment: @charlietfl i would like a completley UTC so GMT envoirment for javascript cause i have the same for php

Comment: I have no idea what that last statement means. Overall you have done very por job of explaing your issue Perhaps you want to look at `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: i'm googling since 3 hours about that don't mind

Comment: update your question so we understand what it is you are trying to do. It currently is not clear at all

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, i think now it's explicit :P

Comment: does this help?  http://jsfiddle.net/grCpY/

Comment: can find a lot if you simply use google

Comment: nope i need to convert serverDate to new ServerDate according to the user timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to set the end date for the countdown in UTC time, as opposed to the local time of the browser.  You *don't* need to modify the plugin to do this.  You just want the `setUTC...` methods in the `Date` object.  Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.

For example:

```
var endofworld = new Date(0);
endofworld.setUTCFullYear(2012);
endofworld.setUTCMonth(11);
endofworld.setUTCDate(21);

$('.countdown').countdown({ date: endofworld });
```

Comment: I've expanded upon my answer, and included an example